# Servicio de Notificaciones se desconecta

Tags: android

Tengo un servicio de Notificaciobnes que al cabo de un par de segundo se desconezta.

```
D/FA: Application going to the background
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

En el manifest.xml tengo esto desnto de la :

```
<service
        android:name=".ServicioNotificaciones"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Y la clase del servicio es  este.  ServicioNotificaciones.java

```
class ServicioNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken( token );
    // Guardar el token del telefono
```

}

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );
    // Recibir Notificaciones Push
    String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0 ){
        String titulo  = remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
        String detalle  = remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
        mayorqueoreo (titulo, detalle);
    }
}

private void  mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle) {
    String id = "mensajes";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this, id );
    //NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( id, "nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH  );
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( id, "nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH  );
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( notificationChannel );
    }
    builder.setAutoCancel( true )
            .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
            .setContentTitle( titulo )
            .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
            .setContentText( detalle )
            .setContentIntent( clicknoti() )
            .setContentInfo( "nuevo" );

    Random random = new Random(  );
    int idNotify = random.nextInt(8000);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify( idNotify, builder.build() );

}

public PendingIntent clicknoti() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
    //intent.putExtra( "color", "rojo" );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 0, intent, 0 );
}
```

¿Por que ocurre esto?. Lo he visto en varios videos y no les pasa esto.
¿Como hay que hacer el servicio para que no pase esto? y no se desconezte.

Si comento lo del manifest.xml y envio una notificacion basica desde firebase si funciona, aunque tarda varios minutos en llevar. Pero es la basica, la clase no entra en funcionamiento.

Gracias.

---

Esto no es una respuesta sino una aclaracion:

Esto es lo que me sale si tengo la app en segundo plano y envio una notificacion desde firebase:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.valhondo.delgado.cofradiainfantil, PID: 19464
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.valhondo.delgado.cofradiainfantil.ServicioNotificaciones: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.valhondo.delgado.cofradiainfantil.ServicioNotificaciones> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4028)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1930)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.valhondo.delgado.cofradiainfantil.ServicioNotificaciones> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:233) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1930) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19464 SIG: 9
```

Como veis algo le passa al servicio que por lo que se ve si entra en funcionamiento

Comment: Hola Fernando, define como public tu servicio!

Answer (score 0):

Veo que defines tu servicio `ServicioNotificaciones` de esta forma:

```
class ServicioNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {
```

Es demasiado importante que tu servicio que extiende de la clase `FirebaseMessagingService` sea definido como publico:

```
public class ServicioNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken( token );
    // Guardar el token del telefono
}
```

si no es definido como public esto puede ser la causa del mensaje de error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
> com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
> java.lang.Class<com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs> is not accessible from
> java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>